# snmpd conf extend : set fixed value instead of execute external script

Tags: configuration, snmp

We have a monitor application, reading info thru snmp.

This app expects to gather some values from snmp extensions, via "extend".

On the monitored hosts, for various reasons (security, performance), we want to set fixed values into the snmpd.conf, instead of executing external scripts.

For example, let create one extension in snmpd.conf:

> extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.1 test  /opt/sysutils/test.sh

I see, with snmpwalk, that snmpd creates 14 OIDs to manage this one !

Question: is it possible to create an extension with a fixed value ?

> extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.7890.1 test "foo bar"